# Attributes not being inherited from parent by subclasses

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm learning to code in python. Currently, I'm at Obstacles and Classes however I have this issue where the attributes doesn't transfer from parent, and sometimes it oddly works. What seems to be the problem?

```
>>> class Things:
    pass

>>> class Inanimate(Things):
    pass

>>> class Animate(Things):
    pass

>>> class Animals(Animate):
    pass

>>> class Mammals(Animals):
    pass

>>> class Giraffes(Mammals):
    pass

>>> class Animals(Animate):
    def breathe(self):
        print("breathes")


>>> class Animals(Animate):
    def move(self):
        print("moves")


>>> class Animals(Animate):
    def eat_food(self):
        print("eats food")


>>> class Animals(Animate):
    def jump(self):
        print("jumps in the air")


>>> class Mammals(Animals):
    def feeds_young_with_milk(self):
        print("feeds young with milk")


>>> class Giraffes(Mammals):
    def eat_leaves_from_trees(self):
        print("eat leaves from trees")


>>> reginald = Giraffes()
>>> reginald.move()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    reginald.move()
AttributeError: 'Giraffes' object has no attribute 'move'
>>> reginal.breathes()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
    reginal.breathes()
NameError: name 'reginal' is not defined
>>> reginald.breathes()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 1, in <module>
    reginald.breathes()
AttributeError: 'Giraffes' object has no attribute 'breathes'
>>> reginald.eat_food()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    reginald.eat_food()
AttributeError: 'Giraffes' object has no attribute 'eat_food'
>>> reginald.jump()
jumps in the air
>>>
```

Comment: Why are you defining the same class 4 times?

Comment: You have defined the `Animals` class 4 times, overwriting the previous class every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike in, say, Ruby, redefining a class doesn't add more stuff to the existing definition. Every time you write `class Animals(Animate): ...`, you're defining an *entirely new* class with no connection to any previous class with that name, and replacing the class object that the name `Animals` used to refer to. The new class doesn't have the methods of the old.

Stop redefining the same classes 5 times. Completely define a class the first time around.